# Powering Arduino by USB

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

The USB cable that came with the Arduino board is not easily recognized by the computer for selecting the appropriate COM port,

For powering the Arduino it works fine (the board will light up when plugged), so why it is not easily recognized by the computer in the device manager?

Comment: What do you mean with "is not easy"? Does is work or doesn't it work?

Comment: it requires you holding it to be detected in the device manager

Comment: Mhh, that should not happen. When something only works, when you touch it, it is often because of a grounding issue. Can you please try a different cable? Maybe the one, that you got with the Arduino, is broken.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a board with a [**micro-usb**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Micro_connectors) connector.  Is that what you have?